# How to Install Netbeans form independent zips?

Tags: netbeans, installation

I downloaded these zip files from the link http://netbeans.org/downloads/zip.html with the hope that this way I will have a fine grained control over the installation process.

But I stand clueles. I can't tell how to install Netbeans from these, there is no installation guide for this.

Any ideas how to install Netbeans this way.

Edit:
I have all the zips availbale with me. I extract them and I find there is no shell script or batch file or a jar which says 'start the ide here' or something like this. e.g. netbeans-6.8-200912041610-ml-ide.zip gives me the directories as config, docs, jsstubs, modules, update_tracking .

Edit2:
I am sorry for not mentioning which files I am talking about. In the second half of the page the download present as Module Clusters are present and I was talking about those.

Comment: Which one did you download and what problem did you have?

Comment: what sort of configs do you want to have in netbeans? Why aren't you prefering the standard installers (.exe)?

Comment: Just unzip Netbeans, point your JRE path in your environment variables and run Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The zip files from the downloads/zip.html page are what gets downloaded when you select a platform independent zip from the main download page, and leave the default language to English.

E.g., if from the main page you select Java SE, English language, and platform independent zip, the actual file that gets downloaded is netbeans-6.8-200912041610-ml-javase.zip listed on the downloads/zip.html page.

---

### Platform-Independent Zip Installation Instructions

Taken from [here](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/install.html#install_zip).

1. After the download of the
   platform-independent ZIP file
   completes, extract it to any folder
   on your system.
2. Run the executable file located in
   the netbeans/bin directory.
3. Accept the License Agreement. The
   NetBeans IDE starts.

   Note: Note that
   the runtimes, such as the GlassFish
   application server and Apache
   Tomcat, are available only with
   platform-specific installers.

Note:
    If the compatible JDK installation
    cannot be found, you might need to
    manually add the path to the JDK
    installation directory:

1. Open the netbeans.conf file located
   at netbeans/etc in a text editor.
2. Enter the location of the compatible
   JDK installation as the value of the
   netbeans_jdkhome option.
3. Save the netbeans.conf file and run
   the executable file at netbeans/bin.

Comment: This method is for the zip independent download on the main download page. Perhaps you should check the link I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to install from zips, but its pretty easy to get fine grained control just using the plugin system. You can uninstall any plugins that come with your download version and you can easily install new plugins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit `[Netbeans_home]\etc\netbeans.conf` file in a text editor.
2. Replace the line `"#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"` with the path to the JDK.
   example:
   `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"`

   note: "#" character needs to be removed, to uncomment this line.
3. Tweak the "netbeans_default_options" parameter also as needed.